# WebKit.NET component not working correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webkit.net

I'm trying to make basic webbrowser in C# in Visual Studio, but I won't use built-in webbrowser component with IE rendering engine. So I downloaded WebKit.NET and added to my project. But it can load only one page - google.com. So when I put google.com to textbox and then press button, it works. But if I put to textbox else adress (toutube.com, facebook.com,...) it does nothing. With buit-in webbrowser everything works fine, but still on IE engine. Where can be mistake? The code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webkitBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
        }
```

Comment: Any error or exception on the output log?

Comment: Nope, it does obsolotely nothing.

Comment: Hmm, for what I see the package is not updated since three years ago... I would recommend to use another browser, the most used is Awesomium: http://www.awesomium.com/

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thank you.